# randomForest::combine() and objects in a list

Tags: r, list, random-forest

In order to run Random Forest models over very large datasets, I have divided my data into chunks and have run randomForest::randomForest() on each chunk. The resulting randomForest objects are contained in a list. I now need to use randomForest::combine() to combine the trees from each chunk of data.

My question is, how do I use a function such as combine() over all objects in a list? In my understanding, sapply(), etc. apply a function to each object in a list--not what I want to do. I need to use combine() over all randomForest objects in the list; or if that is not directly possible, I need to pull out each object separately and send it to combine(). Another issue is that I have different datasets with a varying number of data chunks; I want the code to be flexible in regards to the number of chunks.

My list (rf.final) contains objects "1" through "5" which are each randomForest objects:

```
> class(rf.final)
[1] "list"
> names(rf.final)
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
> class(rf.final[[1]])
[1] "randomForest.formula" "randomForest"
```

There are 5 objects just because I had 5 chunks of data for this particular dataset.

I haven't included `str(rf.final)` because the output is huge [even just for `str(rf.final[[1]])`] but I can if desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution! Use the do.call() function in the base package.

I.e.

```
rf.final2 <- do.call("combine", rf.final)
```